# VM browser indicates different region

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine

I know when I ordered/created my VM in Azure I choose "East US" (6 months back) and even now in the Azure Web console it shows the same. When I signed in to that VM today and opened Firefox and went to www.google.com, I saw the page in Chinese.

Later I also received an email alert from gmail saying it blocked a sign-in attempt (I have a emailing program on that VM that runs in the background and sends application alerts using gmail)

"Someone just used your password to try to sign in to your Google Account @gmail.com, using an application such as an email client or mobile device."

Which confirms that my VM was indeed in China, Hong Kong to be specific.

How can this happen i.e Azure says the region is "East US" and gmail/google says its in China - can someone please help me understand this.

Comment: if the portal says its in "East US" - it is there. Did you configure a proxy? or did you vm get hacked? I dont really see any other options

Comment: Azure can't possibly move a VM to another region without you explicitly taking an action to create one there. You'll need to do some exploration on your VM to figure out what's happening. As written, this question is off-topic for StackOverflow (and also likely off-topic for SuperUser and ServerFault, as this is a very broad question where you've provided no specifics about your setup aside from general region info).

Comment: I wonder how this is at all related to programming. Please read [ask].

Comment: I was searching and reading Azure VM related questions and when i did not find one that answered my doubt I clicking on "Ask Question" (blue button) and I posted my question. I still can't figure out how to find the sub-forum for dev vs programming vs server admin etc.

Comment: Sounds like your VM has been compromised. That being said, Azure will not move your VM to another data center. So if you picked East US it is still there.

Answer (score -1):

With Azure, you can use antimalware software from security vendors such as Microsoft, Symantec, Trend Micro, and Kaspersky to protect your virtual machines from malicious files, adware, and other threats.

You could perform a malware scan using [Microsoft Antimalware](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/security/security-virtual-machines-overview#antimalware)- It is a real-time protection capability that helps identify and remove viruses, spyware, and other malicious software. Microsoft Antimalware provides configurable alerts when known malicious or unwanted software attempts to install itself or run on your Azure systems.

You could review your VM OS/browser language settings for correctness.

To isolate any specific issues with your Google account credential/language/settings, you may try accessing Google/Gmail locally to see if you experience the same behavior. If yes, you would have contact Google support for help.

Additionally, the entire Azure DC range is available in .xml format [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=41653), this list is kept up-to-date and refreshed every week by us.

Comment: Thanks for all the replies.

"David Makogon and Micah said VM is compromised" - can you explain how a VM can be compromised. There is no web application running on this server, that could expose this VM. Its just some background scripts that run locally and get values from the 2 websites using Python (BeautifulSoup)

The only way I access this sever is from my home PC using Remote Desktop - yes desktop is disconnected without locking - is that an issue?